# Traer una url con caracteres espciales

Tags: java, json, webservice, netbeans

tengo un web service hecho en java en el IDE de Netbeans, en el cual quiero traer devuelta una url que contiene caracateres especiales como los sigos +
ejemplo de url :
http://localhost:8080/WSv2/webresources/generic/buscarporcurso?courseDisplayName=course-v1%3AU+AIRPOLLUTION+2017_ENE

Cuando uso el metodo get para taer devuelta el valor a consultar (es decir el nombre del curso "course-v1%3AU+AIRPOLLUTION+2017_ENE"), me devuelve lo siguiente: course-v1:U AIRPOLLUTION 2017_ENE
haciendo que los signos + se muestren como espacios en blanco.
Como puedo hacer para que la url que me devuelva el metodo get incluya a los signos + es decir (course-v1:U+AIRPOLLUTION+2017_ENE)

Codigo

```
@GET
@Path("/buscarporcurso")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getBycourseDisplayName(@QueryParam("courseDisplayName") String curso, @QueryParam("callback") String callback) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    EdxTrackEventDao obj = new EdxTrackEventDao();
    EdxTrackEvent c = null;
    try{
     c = obj.buscar("courseDisplayName", curso);
    }catch( Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }


    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    array.add(c.getAnonScreenName());



    Gson g = new Gson();
    String formatoJSON = g.toJson(array);
        if (callback != null) {
            return Response.ok(callback + "(" + formatoJSON + ")", "application/json;charset=UTF-8").status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(formatoJSON, "application/json;charset=UTF-8").status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La parte del servidor está correcta, los espacios en blanco no son caracteres válidos en una URL<sup>1</sup>, se substituyen por `+` en la URL y el servidor hace la conversión inversa.

Puedes hacer una prueba rápida visitando google y haciendo una búsqueda que contenga un espacio en blanco, verás como el espacio se convierte en `+`.

Lo que tienes que hacer es enviar el valor correctamente codificado en la URL. Por ejemplo, si lo haces desde Java, puedes usar la clase [`java.net.URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html); por ejemplo

```
 String urlCodificada = URLEncoder.encode(
   "http://localhost:8080/WSv2/webresources/generic/buscarporcurso?courseDisplayName=course-v1%3AU+AIRPOLLUTION+2017_ENE",
   "UTF-8");
```

---

<sup>1</sup>O al menos lo eran, con las URLs en Unicode no estoy tan seguro. Pero de cualquier forma los navegadores siguen convirtiendo los espacios en blanco a `+` al pasar parametros, por lo que el servidor sigue interpretando el `+` como que el valor es un espacio en blanco codificado.